# Why the response from API is empty?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

When I made a request firstly I got "Blocked by CORS" error, coz I had different Access-Control-Allow-Origin, after this I set mode to 'no-cors', now request gives me an empty response, is that because I need a correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin?
P.S Thats not my API, and I have never write APIs by myself, so I don't really understand this situation.
I tried to google it, but all that I found is the solution for backend, use cors packege etc.

```
const res = await fetch('http://api.brain.com.ua/categories', {
     method: 'GET',
     mode : 'no-cors',
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     }
})
```